# Sptinrg: @OneToMany multiplicity does not work

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes `Writting` and `User`. A user may have one or many Writings. I would like to make a table using these to classes with `hibernate`. 
I used [this](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) link as tutorial.
I have added the proper dependencies for hibernate, and lombock in my pom.xml:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    Collection<Writting> writings=new ArrayList<Writting>() ;
}
```

and then the `Writting` is:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Writting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    User user;
}
```

As a result, i expect it gives me an extra table which consists of `foreign key of user`, and `foreign key of writtings`. But, **there is no such table?**

Comment: @luk2302 i don't get my mistake from your command. can u explain more?

Comment: @JBNizet what is a `drumrolls`? can u explain more?

Comment: ur a user with high reputation. i don't expect it from u.Could u please write an answer? @JBNizet

Comment: Having a sense of humor is not incompatible with having a high reputation. Relax. Take it easy. The documentation totally lacks humor, so you can read it safely. It also has the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have tried gives u one extra column in your `Writting` table, which keeps the `user_Id`. In this case, you have successfully made a bio-directional relationship between user, and writting.

But, if you want the hibernate gives you an extra table, then you must remove this:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    User user;
```

In this case, you are saying that, I want every `user` knows all his `writtings`, but you cannot get the `user` out of `writting`. And it makes you a new table. called `USER_WRITINGS`

Comment: @JB Nizet do u approve it?

Comment: It's correct: OneToMany unidirectional associations are mapped, by default, using a join table. But if you want to keep it bidirectional, and want it to be mapped with a join table, you just need to annotate the user with JoinTable instead of JoinColumn.